# Separating txt (conversation) into columns with speaker names as variables

Tags: r

I'm new to text mining in R. I have multiple txt files of conversations between the same speakers organized as follows:

```
speaker one [speakers' names are on their own line]
what speaker one says [paragraph of each speaker's speech after 
line break from name]
[empty line]
speaker two
what speaker two says
[empty line]
speaker one
what speaker one replies
[empty line]
speaker three
what speaker three says
...
```

I want to break up the texts into one row per text with columns as the names of speakers. I want to have everything that speaker one says in each text combined in one cell on each row and the same for other speakers. Something like this:

```
text   "speaker one"                "speaker two"              ...
text1  everything speaker one said  everything speaker two said
text2  everything speaker one said  everything speaker two said
...
```

Any help on how to get started would be appreciated.

Comment: Are these earnings transcripts? If not, are what a speaker says in multiple paragraphs, seperated by an empty line, or is it always just one paragraph?

Comment: Sometimes it's in one paragraph. At other times each sentence is on its own line with no empty line between them (just line breaks). The empty lines are only between different speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some tidyverse packages you can get there. First read the text with `readr::read_file`, next split on the empty line, use `readr::read_delim` to read this into data.frames. As the data is now in a list, using `bind_rows` will collapse all of this into one data.frame. `bind_rows` matches on the column names so that all the text of a speaker is in the correct column. Depending on which outcome you want either the first or the second solution.

I leave combining multiple text files up to you.

```
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# read file into a character vector
text <- readr::read_file("conversation.txt")

# split the text on the empty line
split_text <- strsplit(text, split = "\r\n\r\n")

# read the data in again with read_delim. This will generate a list of data.frames
list_text <- lapply(unlist(split_text), function(x) readr::read_delim(x, col_names = TRUE, delim = "\t"))

# use bind_rows from dplyr to combine everything into 1 tibble. bind_rows matches on the column names.
list_text %>% 
  bind_rows

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  `speaker one`                                                      `speaker two`         `speaker three`         
  <chr>                                                              <chr>                 <chr>                   
1 what speaker one says is in this paragraph.                        NA                    NA                      
2 It might be in multiple lines, but not seperated by an empty line. NA                    NA                      
3 NA                                                                 what speaker two says NA                      
4 what speaker one replies                                           NA                    NA                      
5 NA
```

Collapsing all the text in one line:

This needs a bit more work with first gathering the data in a tidy long format, collapsing the text and then spreading it wide again. Run the statements in chunks if you want to see what is happening in each step.

```
list_text %>% 
  bind_rows %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), 
               names_to = "speakers",
               values_to = "text",
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(speakers) %>% 
  summarise(text = paste0(text, collapse = " ")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = speakers, values_from = text)

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  `speaker one`                                                                                   `speaker three`       `speaker two`     
  <chr>                                                                                           <chr>                 <chr>             
1 what speaker one says is in this paragraph. It might be in multiple lines, but not seperated b~ what speaker three s~ what speaker two ~
```

**text used in text file conversation.txt**

```
speaker one
what speaker one says is in this paragraph.
It might be in multiple lines, but not seperated by an empty line.

speaker two
what speaker two says

speaker one
what speaker one replies

speaker three
what speaker three says.
```